# Changing the order of integration in the proof that Laplace maps convolution to multiplication

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convolution

I was reading the proof that Laplace transform maps the convolution of two functions to the multiplication of their transforms. Or mathematically
$$\mathcal{L}[f*g]=\mathcal{L}[f]\,\mathcal{L}[g],$$
with
$$\mathcal{L}[f](s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t)dt$$
and
$$f*g(t)=\int_0^t f(\tau)g(t-\tau)d\tau.$$

In the proof it is written
$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^t e^{-st} f(\tau)g(t-\tau)d\tau dt=\int_0^\infty \int_\tau ^\infty e^{-st} f(\tau)g(t-\tau) dt d\tau.$$

The justification is 2 pictures that show that these integrals go through the same area. You can see this [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-iii-fourier-series-and-laplace-transform/transfer-system-and-weight-functions-greens-formula/MIT18_03SCF11_s30_5text.pdf), page 2.

I understand this but I believe the same could be proved just with changes in the integration variables. However I could not figure this out. Can this be done analytically?

Edit:
I assume that $f$ and $g$ are analytic and $|f(t)|,|g(t)| \le M e^{a|t|}$. It is easy to prove that $|f*g(t)|\le M' e^{a|t|}$. Then $\mathcal{L}[f*g](s)$ is defined for $\mbox{Re}\, s> a$. So in particular I can't assume that $f(t)=g(t)=0$ when $t<0$.

My goal is to prove something similar but instead of integration over a line, I have integration over a path. That's why I want an analytic way for the change.